# customized user id in User table in laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

Helo I am trying to assign a user id with some prefixes like `PS00` and save it in user table while user registration.

I have tried mutators in laravel

```
public function setProfileIdAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['profile_id'] = "PS00".$this->id;
}
```

But unable to add `profile_id` to table, as it says `profile_id` can not be null.

Comment: ok i did it myself

Comment: How about posting an answer?

Comment: use sprintf. $user->profile_id =sprintf('PS%06d', $user->id);
        $user->save();